# User remains connected even if I close the chrome page open with Visual Studio - Asp Net Identity Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a Web Application who contains Identity authetication.
If I start the web application from Visual Studio, I login into web appliocation and then I close the chrome page. If I restart the web application, login page is displayed, but when I type the right credentials and I press ENTER, the page goes into `400` error.

In order to perform the right login process, I must type `/` at the end of the url `https://localhost:[PORT]` and all goes right.

I think that this problem is correlated with authentication cookie. How I can solve this problem?

Comment: What;s the 400 bad request's detail error message? Besides, I suggest you could try to set the log level to verbose and check the console or VS logs to see why the server return the 400 to the client when the user access. Without the details error message, we don't know why this happened.